# MySQL Stored Procedure SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I'm coming from an Oracle world where I can use DBMS_SQL for dynamic SQL with an unknown number of bind variables.  Apparently this is not possible in MySQL.  So my question is how do you protect against SQL Injection in MySQL?  I thought this would be easy to lookup but every example I find is with PHP & MySQL.  I'm only dealing with MySQL stored procedures, no PHP.  Here is a snippet:

```
set @sql_string=concat(@sql_string,'col1=''',someRandomText,''' where col2=''',moreRandomText,''';');
```

Is there a protection function that could be applied to `someRandomText` to prevent SQL Injection (http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the `someRandomText` input to the SP come from? It is usually escaped there, in the application layer. There is a native [`QUOTE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) string function that can be used in some contexts.

Comment: The data is already in the DB.  It's import data that is held in a temp table.  This is part of an import process.  As the stored proc runs and moves data from staging to production tables is where I need the protection.

Comment: The native `QUOTE()` string function may work for you. In practice, I don't think I have _ever_ seen it used because input more commonly comes from outside the DB.  Did you already escape it at the application layer before it goes into the temp table?

Comment: I did not know of that function.  Thank you!  I'll look into that.